# python how to raise Exception without breaking a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, exception, python-asyncio

lets say I have some event listener that suppose to run all the time and there is some `exceptions` that I want to pass them to the function caller something like that

```
import asyncio

_ = 0

async def listener(loop):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        if _ != 0:
            raise ValueError('the _ is not 0 anymore!')
        print('okay')

async def executor(loop):
    while True:
        x = await loop.run_in_executor(None, input, 'execute: ')
        global _
        _ = x

async def main(loop):
    asyncio.ensure_future(listener(loop), loop=loop)
    await executor(loop)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

if you gonna change the value the listener event loop will brake but **I dont want it to `break` I want it to `raise` the error so you will be able to catch it and the `loop` to keep going**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont want it to break I want it to raise the error so you will be able to catch it and the loop to keep going

If you want to raise the error but keep going, then the listener shouldn't `raise` directly. Instead, it should signal the exception to the interesting parties using a `Future` object. Instead of awaiting the executor, `main()` should await the broadcast future in a loop:

```
import asyncio

_ = 0
broadcast = None

async def listener():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        if _ != 0:
            broadcast.set_exception(ValueError('the _ is not 0 anymore!'))
        else:
            print('okay')

async def executor():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        x = int(await loop.run_in_executor(None, input, 'execute: '))
        global _
        _ = x

async def main():
    global broadcast
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(listener())
    loop.create_task(executor())
    while True:
        broadcast = loop.create_future()
        try:
            await broadcast
        except ValueError as e:
            print('got error', e)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```